# Xpages and OrientDB - how to handle connection object properly?

Tags: xpages

We would like to involve OrientDB (http://www.orientechnologies.com/) into the one of our Xpages projects. It suites well for our purposes using DocumentDatabase part of OrientDB.

Here we found a problem of how to deal with connection object. Instead of connecting and disconnecting manualy on every request we would like to use some shared connection for entire application. Documentation talks about it here https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Java-Web-Apps but its servlet filter, which is not suitable for Domino. Is there anyone having solution working properly with Domino and Xpages?

Comment: I have no experience with OrientDB, but it seems that there is a JDBC driver available. In that case, the ExtLib offers connection pooling out-of-the-box. If for some reason you need to implement your own pool, the logic is not really that hard (a bean could be worth a try). As @Fredrik Norling said, the ExtLib sources are a good starting point (e.g. com\ibm\xsp\extlib\jdbc\datasource\xpages\JdbcPoolConnection.java). Btw, I agree about the lack of documentation. But, do not hesitate about asking more questions, we definitely need more XPages+JDBC questions and answers here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a custom datasource and within this datasource handle to connection pooling
look at this presentation
http://www.slideshare.net/NotesSensei/show107-the-datasource-session-take-xpages-data-boldly-where-no-xpages-data-has-been-taken-before

or check how it's done within the extension library sources. http://extlib.openntf.org/

a post about the connecting to jdbc using java
http://lazynotesguy.net/blog/2013/08/09/subclassing-an-extlib-component/

Comment: Hmm :-( but generaly I'm trying to avoid these things. Its a world of almost no documentation, support or anything. I'm experimenting with XSP Starter Kit from openNTF for 3 months now but no luck. My collegue followed documentation fro XSP Starter Kit ... also with no luck. No support here and there. We were trying to create our own update site similar to Extensions Library also with no luck. There is no real documentation except of some hello world like tutorials for these things.

Comment: You need to be careful what approach you pick. JDBC is the obvious temptation here. However it most likely will deprive you of OrientDB capabilities (like graph queries) or make them more complicated. This might help: http://www.slideshare.net/NotesSensei/show107-the-datasource-session-take-xpages-data-boldly-where-no-xpages-data-has-been-taken-before

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should be able to do is use an ApplicationListener in your App that will allow you to create the object on startup of the app and shut it down when the application is pulled out of memory.

Comment: Application listener http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=740 contains 'applicationDestroyed' and 'applicatinRefreshed' methods but unfortunately both run after refresh and after app destroy ... what means, that if you on 'applicationCreated' event store connection e.g. in application scope bean, you can't e.g. close connection on 'applicationDestroyed' because this event is run after entire Xpages environment is destroyed already so the application managed bean doesnt exist.

Comment: It wouldn't have to use a managed bean, you could use an Application Wide singleton to hold the object.